# Set block over the HERE map

Tags: html, css, here-api

I try to do such thing with web page with HERE maps
[image]

Grey block is a block where map should be situated(i did that when wifi was turned off).
The html code is:

```
<div id="map" style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; background:grey;z-index:0">
    <div style="position:absolute;">
        <div class="forbut">
            <button onclick="myFunction()" class="btn-danger">edf</button>
        </div>
        <div id="list" style=" width:100px; left:0;  background-color: red; z-index:1">

        </div>
        <div style="position:absolute; left:600px;top:0">
            <div class="forbut1">
                <button onclick="myFunction1()" class="btn-danger">edf</button>
            </div>
            <div id="list1" style=" width:100px; left:600px;  background-color: red; z-index:1">

            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
```

But when wifi is turned on, blocks with buttons dissapears regardless that those blocks have bigger 'z-index' value than map-container
[image]
How make blocks with buttons be over the map?

Comment: Try those styles for the #map element: `position: relative;width: 100vw;height: 100vh;background:grey;z-index:0;`

Comment: unfortunatelly, that gives the same result

Answer (score 0):

It is not fully clear for me what you try to achieve, but from my perspective adding the z-index to the first child container of the parent div should suffice. Nevertheless, I would recommend in general against adding anything to the container that is passed to the map. There are two options, either to build UI in the container that is parent to the div with the id=“map” or use libraries UI module and build custom buttons with it.